# Determine location text on image

Tags: html, css

I have to keep position of text, when the text changed.

Thanks for help.

```html
<span>
    <a href="javascript:moveToNewWindow('userRecords.htmpl');">
        <img id="MyCalls" src="btn-mycalls-reg.png" style="cursor:pointer; width:208px;height:124px;" onmouseover="hoverMyCalls(this)" onmouseout="origMyCalls(this)">
    </a>
    <span class="countCalls" id="countCallsId" style="
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.60em;
    right: 52.2em;
">1</span>
</span>
```

source image
[image: image source]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you've written userRecords.htmpl instead of userRecords.html, please change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you give the layer a width 100% then you can use text-center to center the number in the middle.

Note that the `top: 2.5em;` is related to the font-size. In this case you can also use px because the image has an absolute size of 208x124 px

```
<span>
  <a href="javascript:moveToNewWindow('userRecords.html');">
    <img id="MyCalls" src="btn-mycalls-reg.png" onmouseover="hoverMyCalls(this)" onmouseout="origMyCalls(this)">
  </a>
  <span class="countCalls" id="countCallsId">123</span>
</span>
```

with css

```
/* span as container */
span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}
/* image */
#MyCalls {
  width: 208px;
  height: 124px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* layer on image */
#countCallsId {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5em;
  left: 0;
  /* next line: not 100% for better centering */
  width: 99.9%;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```